"Small" formulas for boolean functions
Theorem 10 in the following document:
https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/topics-S13/lec1.pdf
states that every boolean function $f:\{0, 1\}^n\rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ has formula complexity $O(2^n/\log n)$. I was trying to prove this but couldnt. Also couldn't find a source. How does one prove this?

This is not that easy to prove. See e.g. Theorem 3.2 in Ingo Wegener, Complexity of Boolean functions.
